# Hide Show Specific Columns complex

Tags: excel, vba

first of all I'm a n00b both here and with VBA.
I have also spent a few hours reading through similar problems than the one I'm trying to solve with little success.
I'm trying to come up with a way to hide/show specific columns based on the value of a cell "A1".
The problem is that I have about 200 columns and the only way I've found to manage is through a many lines code with all the ranges (see below).

I was wondering two things:

1) Is there a more efficient way of coding this so that I don't need so many lines? and
2) Ideally:  Is there a way of coding this so that it would actually look at the value in the excel row and hide those columns for which the cells don't contain "Q1"?

Thanks guys :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then
    Columns("G:I").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("K:Z").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("AB:AQ").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("AS:BH").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("BJ:BY").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("CA:CP").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("CR:DG").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("CR:DG").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("DI:DX").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
    Columns("DZ:EO").Hidden = Target.Value = "Q1"
```

...etc.

[image]

Comment: You may like to look at the solution presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403545/hide-rows-based-on-choice. In that case specific rows are to be hidden based on changes in certain cells. This could easily be adapted to show and hide columns instead. It's more versatile than you require in that it can respond to multiple cells but perhaps that's a feature that would suit your own project even better than what you have in mind so far.

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide all columns where the header is not equal to whatever is in A1, or do you only want to handle the "Q1" value?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing a bit at what you really want to do...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng as range, c as range, rngHide as range
    If Target.Address() = Me.Range("A1").Address() Then
        set rng = me.range("G14:EO14")
        rng.entirecolumn.hidden = false
        If target.value = "ALL" then exit sub '<<< show all
        for each c in rng.cells
            If c.value <> Target.Value then
                if rngHide is nothing then
                    set rngHide = c
                Else
                    set rngHide = Application.Union(rngHide, c)
                end if
            end if
        next c  
        If not rngHide is nothing then rnghide.entirecolumn.hidden = true
     End if
End Sub
```